# I need to use this function in a program but the output is freezing for some reason

Tags: c++, function, series

Here is the correct function:

```
double SumSeries()
{
    int fact = 1, n, sign = -1, factnum = 3;
    float sum = 0, term, x;
    cout<<"How many terms: ";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<endl<<"Enter value of x: ";
    cin>>x;
    sum += x;
    for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        fact = 1;
        for(int j =1; i <= factnum; j++)
            fact *= j;
        term = pow(x, i)/fact * sign;
        sum += term;
        factnum += 2;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I have tried several ways but the output hangs after this:
[image]

Comment: What are your inputs? What have you observed when stepping through with a debugger, or by placing `std::cout` statements throughout your code?

Comment: Voting to close for typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In inner loop `for(int j =1; i <= factnum; j++)`. You hav eused `i` instead of `j` in conditional part of loop. So it is going in infinite loop.
To correct your code just change `i <= factnum;` to `j <= factnum;` in inner loop.